# Setting null value through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an OptionSet whose default value is "Unassigned", which shows as blank to a user browsing the form.

On certain conditions, I have to clear the option set and set its value back to "Unassigned".

Here's the code that I have:

```
Xrm.Page.Data.Entity.Attributes.Get("fieldName").setValue(null);
```

That indeed does change the value to "Unassigned" and shows the option set with a blank, but it doesn't seem like this is what gets committed to the database.

If I run an Advanced Find, I still see the old value that was there prior to running the code above on it.

Anything I'm missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute([fieldname]).setSubmitMode("always");
```

Sometimes when values are changed by script (especially when they are read only) CRM doesn't pick up the change.

Comment: Woot, works wonderfully! Thanks. Btw, where could I have found this on MSDN ? Xrm seems to be the root namespace, is it the "XRM Framework" or something ?

Comment: In here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx, I usually Google for something like: MSDN CRM JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Instead of google I would recommend starting with this link (which I can't take credit for!):

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/04/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-javascript.html

There is a link to a skydrive document which has a comprehensive cheat sheet for all the Xrm Namespace functions. Worth its weight in gold!